# read string with whitespaces from file

Tags: c++, string, text, file-io

So basically, i'm making a simple program that takes names from file s and then asks if they should be written to another file.

```
void ziureti(){
      string pavadinimas, statymas, laimejo;
      double kofas; //these are irrelevant to the problem
      int suma; //these are irrelevant to the problem
      cout << "Enter the name: ";
      getline(cin, statymas);
      ifstream fd (FV);
      while (statymas != pavadinimas ){ //out here I iterate through the file until i find the neccesary name
      fd >> pavadinimas;}
```

So when the name is either only numbers or letters its fine, but when there's both the program doesn't find them. Any ideas?

For example

```
Chelsea
10
1.8
Arsenal
15
2.3
Chelsea Arsenal
15
1.85
```

`Chelsea Arsenal` is supposed to be a single string, how would I do that?

Comment: Can you give an example of an input file that fails?

Comment: Alright I'm sorry, I messed up file names and saving, but still it doesn't work when there is whitespace in string. How would i fix that?
`
Chelsea
10
1.8
Arsenal
15
2.3
Chelsea Arsenal (this is supposed to be one string)
15
1.85
`
@celtschk

Comment: `operator>>` splits at spaces. You probably want to use `getline` on `fd` as well.

Comment: @Marsietis Please edit your question to add additional information. In comments it's pretty useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
fd >> pavadinimas;        // ">>" will stop parsing when hitting spaces
```

to

```
getline(fd, pavadinimas); // will parse the whole line
```